# Trouble with apache derby user password

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I use netbeans for devolp software. On mac I have created a derby db with user e password.
I have copy the db on windows pc and by netbeans I can't access at the db. Error password incorrect. Where is the error in this procedure?

Comment: How *exactly* did you copy the database?

Comment: I copy using os function copy

Comment: Was the database online when you performed the OS copy? Also, you can't perform a OS copy from Mac to Windows; did you use FTP? SCP? Samba?

Comment: I don't use the db for a web app. I use the db embededd into a java desktop project. I copy the db directory from Mac to Windows. Only move file from 1 computer to other computer

Comment: **How** did you perform the copy? Not all copy operations are performed in binary. Also, if the DB was open then that won't fork. Finally, I'm not sure you can copy the file from the filesystem across OS you might have to perform a DB export / import

Comment: The database format used by Derby is portable and platform-independent, so it should in general be straightforward to copy the database from the Mac to the PC. If the database has a password, then of course you'll need the password to access the database, no matter what machine you copy it to.